# "Distributed" membership approval in LinkedIn Groups

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-groups

In LinkedIn Groups, is it possible to allow all members to approve pending membership requests?

Facebook has this feature and it is a great boon to group membership for restricted-entry communities (like [alumni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alumni_association)).